# material-ui how to override nested styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple Material-UI component

```
    <Chip
      avatar={
        <Avatar>
          <TruckIcon color='primary' />
        </Avatar>
      }
      label={name}
      color='primary'
    />
```

the following styles applied from mui-theme:

```
.MuiChip-root .MuiChip-avatarColorPrimary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #21349f;
}
```

The question is how to override it?

I have tried many options in my theme override styles:

```
MuiChip: {
 avatarColorPrimary : {
  background-color: red;
}


    MuiChip: {
      root: {
        avatarColorPrimary  : {
           background-color: red;
          }
       }
    }

MuiChip: {
 '& .avatarColorPrimary': {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but none of them is working.
I'm using 4.9.5 version of Material-UI.

Comment: Add a sandbox, please

Answer (score 2):

The most useful resource when trying to determine the appropriate way to override a style is to look at how the default styles are defined in the source code.

Below is an excerpt of the default styles from the [Chip source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.5/packages/material-ui/src/Chip/Chip.js#L52):

```
{
   root: {
     '& $avatarColorPrimary': {
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
      }
   }
}
```

Below is an example of overriding the background color in the theme:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiChip: {
      root: {
        "& $avatarColorPrimary": {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function Chips() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Chip
        avatar={
          <Avatar>
            <DoneIcon color="primary" />
          </Avatar>
        }
        label="Sample Name"
        color="primary"
      />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Chip avatar background]